# Google Maps Cordova

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am using google maps in a ionic/cordova project. I have searched a lot but not found a solution. I need to hide the myLocationButton which centers the app but i need the center dot which shows my location to be there. If i give the value false to myLocation button it hides both.

I tried other way that i creatde my own marker and the centered to it. but it is not the solution that i really want. Any help would be appreciated.

Need to hide center button but need the center dot.

regards
bhanu

Answer (score 0):

(v1.4/v2.0 common)

Normal JS code

```
var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div, {
  'controls': {
    'myLocationButton': false
  }
});
```

v1.4 https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Map/setOptions/README.md

v2.0 https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.0.0/class/Map/getMap/README.md#create-a-map-with-initialize-options

---

ionic code

```
let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element, {
  'controls': {
    'myLocationButton': false
  }
});
```

Comment: HI.. Sorry but this is not what i asked.. i want the center button to be hidden .myLocationButton: false also hides the center dot. I want the center dot to be there and want to get hold of the center button and hide it.. any idea for that?

Comment: The plugin does not provide the option to show/hide the dot and the button separately.